# Parallel connection to Wiegand 26bit RFID readers

Tags: communication

I have situation where I need to read RFID cards. There is already installed Roger security system, Roger gate control board and two rfid readers in parallel. By default board and RFID readers communicate in RACS(some sort of coded protocol) but at the moment system is configured to communicate in Wiegand26. Earlier I used chinese wiegand26 reader with Arduino with no problem.

With Arduino I need to read card read by RFID readers.
Then I process data and make HTTP POST request.
Arduino is supplied from Roger board ~13.5V DC I do not get anything in arduino, even if I connect RFID readers directly to arduino.

- CLK is D0 to Arduino Nano pin 2
- DTA is D1 to Arduino Nano pin 3

This question is not related only to Arduino.

I want to ask is it possible to do? To read data maybe I need some additional electronics?

What i also noticed that when Arduino is connected in parallel the Roger board not always reads the card from RFID readers.

Roger [PR402-BRD](http://www.roger.pl/en/products-to-be-discontinued/760-pr402-brd-access-controller.html)
And two readers [PRT62LT](http://www.roger.pl/en/access-control/readers/proximity-readers-em-125-khz/805-prt62lt-proximity-reader-em-125-khz.html)
[image]

This is copy of [Electronics.stackexchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/177168/58967)

Answer (score 2):

It looks to me like the Wiegand interface is an open-collector interface (like I2C), which is why they can be wired in parallel like that.

As long as the Arduino has both connections set to `INPUT` (not `INPUT_PULLUP` and certainly NOT `OUTPUT`) it shouldn't interfere at all.

By the way, for Wiegand, the two signals are DATA0 and DATA1.  To transmit a 0 the DATA0 line is pulled low. To transmit a 1 the DATA1 line is pulled low.

You should also check that the idle voltage on the lines is indeed 5V as it should be.  Anything more than that could cause the Arduino to chip the voltage to 5V through its internal ESD protection diodes.

Also you must ensure that the Arduino has its ground pin connected to the ground connection of the Wiegand system (which it should be since you are powering it from that).

Comment: i am using https://github.com/monkeyboard/Wiegand-Protocol-Library-for-Arduino library pinMode(D0Pin, INPUT);     // Set D0 pin as input
 pinMode(D1Pin, INPUT);     // Set D1 pin as input
 attachInterrupt(0, ReadD0, FALLING); // Hardware interrupt - high to low pulse
 attachInterrupt(1, ReadD1, FALLING); // Hardware interrupt - high to low pulse

Comment: As you can see `pinMode(D0Pin, INPUT);`. Checked the voltage and for my surprise its ~11,5V `DATA0 - GND -> 11,5V` and same with `DATA1 - GND -> 11,5V` and yes as you said Arduino chips it to 5V when connected

Comment: That could be your problem then - the Arduino would be trying to clamp that to 5V which would cause problems I would guess.  It could also damage the Arduino.  You would probably need to isolate the Arduino from those lines.  Optocouplers would probably be your best bet.

Comment: Hmm, but if i will put optocouplers then led in optocoupler will lower the voltage too? I mean resistor+led in series.

Comment: Depends on the amount of pullup resistance.  Another option could be to use MOSFETs.  You can calculate the pullup resistance by measuring the current to ground then using Ohm's law - you can then work out a suitable resistance for the LED.  Or with a MOSFET you just need to ensure the threshold level is in the right region to switch on/off at the right times. There's all sorts of ways of doing it.  Op-amps could even be used to apply a fractional gain.

Comment: With optocoupler i would need this circuit http://i.stack.imgur.com/edSjI.png ? Will it work and not interfere Wiegand?

Comment: Also i am thinking that MAX232 chip should work here?

Comment: If the resistor is high enough (which also relies on the pullup resistor being low enough) then it may not interfere, but chances are it will.  The MAX232 is a great idea!  Certainly worth giving it a go.  Could be the best bet all round really.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25233/discussion-between-martynas-and-majenko).

Comment: So i will need to invert the signal on Arduino? If i put +12 to MAX232 pin 8 on pin 9 i read 0V. `attachInterrupt(0, ReadD0, FALLING);` line will have to be changed to `attachInterrupt(0, ReadD0, RISING);` ??

Comment: Yep.  The MAX232 inverts.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to use more than 1 Wiegand reader, technically it should be possible to use **AVR pin change interrupt**. In this case you can use ANY 2 pins, even analog pins.

For example, see http://thewanderingengineer.com/2014/08/11/arduino-pin-change-interrupts/

**UPD:** There is informationon Wiegand timing, might be useful:
http://proxclone.com/wiegand.html