# How to read an RFID reader?

Tags: rfid

I want to connect an RFID reader to an Arduino board. The RFID reader has several wires attached, and the manual mentions them as follows:

- Red: VCC +12V
- Black: GND
- Green: D 0/RX/4R+
- White: D 1/TX/4R−
- Blue: LED/CS
- Yellow: Beep

There is also another black wire attached, but the manual does not mention it.
This is an image of it:

[image: Image of RFID reader]

I have the red wire connected to the 5V pin and the black wire to the GND pin on Arduino board. Then I have the white wire connected to the RX pin on the Arduino board.

I'm trying to Serial-read the RX port using this code:

```c
void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
        int b = Serial.read();
        Serial.print(b);
        Serial.print(" ");
    }
}
```

When I try to read a keyfob, only this is printed – nineteen times `248`:

```
248 248 248 248 248 248 248 248 248 248 248 248 248 248 248 248 248 248 248
```

To me it looks like there's something wrong with the connection somewhere.

How can I properly read this RFID reader? If above assumption is not correct, is there something I should know?

Comment: Which RFID reader? Please post a part number or photograph. Please post all your code.

Comment: @NickGammon It's a cheap-ass RFID reader from China. They usually don't put a manufacturer's name or model number on it. I also have posted all my code, but that doesn't make it more clear.

Comment: Do you not have a phone with a camera in it? Anyway, this might help: [RFID reader - HZ-1050](http://www.gammon.com.au/forum/?id=12849)

Comment: Are you 100% sure the fobs' standard matches the reader? Check if the ISO standards are the same.

Comment: @FuaZe Yeah, if I plug the RFID reader into an Access controller, everything's working.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried other baud rates? Could you paste a link to the manual or upload the manual itself? From what i could find quickly, the module supports 3 modes: RS232, RS485 and Wiegand 26/34. So the manual should provide some means of selecting a particular mode (perhaps the CS pin?). I suspect you arent actually using the RS232 mode, which is why you are getting strange results. If you can't find a way to select a mode, you could try brute-forcing it and try the WG26 mode next. This code from seeedstudio seems to do the job http://www.seeedstudio.com/depot/datasheet/RFID_630_WG.pde or you could look at the Wiegand protocol on Wikipedia and write your own code, since its relatively straight forward. Also a google image search turned up this link to Aliexpress: http://www.aliexpress.com/item/Waterproof-Security-Door-Access-Control-Wiegand-26-125KHz-RFID-ID-Card-Reader-EM4100-102A/1362129655.html; this is your reader, right?

Comment: That link looks much like his pic, and says "Output mode: Standard Wiegand26 Format For Access control "  so maybe http://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/12927/parallel-connection-to-wiegand-26bit-rfid-readers would help.

Comment: Yeah, thats what i thought when i found the Aliexpress page, but his post says it supports 2 other modes according to his manual, so i'm not so sure. However, if there is a default mode, its probably the WG26 mode. From the link you provided, it looks like theres already a library (no surprise) that translates Wiegand https://github.com/monkeyboard/Wiegand-Protocol-Library-for-Arduino so its another option, i guess

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience, you should give some init time to the rfid reader to init.

Try to use a digital output to control the chip reset, and give it some milliseconds to init.

I had a similar behavior with a rfid reader and the reason was this I just told.

Good luck!